# Cannot debug native library of Android apk

Tags: apk

・I am debugging an apk file.

・The address I want to stop at BreakPoint is in the native library(.so) (no function name).

・The native library has a "JNI_OnLoad" function, so I set BreakPoint.
　After starting the apk with "adb shell am start -a ・・・", I connected with IDA Pro RemoteDebugger.
　Then I connected with "jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach...".

・However, even though I keep pressing F9, the native library(.so) I want to analyze does not appear.
　It crashes after going back and forth between libc.so and linker.

・When I run "memory module list" using objection, the native library(.so) I want to analyze appears.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked function in init_array section? Maybe there are some anti-debug measures before JNI_ONLOAD was executed such as a infinity loop?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I had not checked the init_array because there were over 400 functions in it.
I knew you are taking countermeasures.
If you have a better way to identify where the countermeasures are being taken, I'd be glad to know.